# GCP spark structured streaming from Pub/Sub

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Is there any solution available for spark streaming to read from Pub/Sub.I have seen the GCP documentation for pub/sub lite [Apache Spark Structured Streaming connector for Pub/Sub Lite](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/pubsub-lite-for-your-streaming-applications)

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/using-apache-spark-dstreams-with-dataproc-and-pubsub), you can create a Spark streaming app in DataProc to consume messages from PubSub, in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/using-apache-spark-dstreams-with-dataproc-and-pubsub#reference_architecture) the architecture is explained. Would it be what you are looking for ?

Comment: I was trying to create a spark streaming app in Azure Databricks.The DataProc  is available only in GCP platform.